# NameError: name 'f_num' is not defined in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, calculator, nameerror

I'm trying to program my calculator project to perform operations. It can perform addition and I want it to
perform the remaining four (minus, multiplication, division, powers)
But I'm stuck because of this error:

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
   "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Calculator GUI v1.0.py"
   Exception in Tkinter callback
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Admin\Python3.9\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Calculator GUI v1.0.py", line 32, in 
    button_subtract
     e.insert(0, f_num + int(second_number))
    NameError: name 'f_num' is not defined

   Process finished with exit code 0
```

My code:

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *

root_var = Tk()
root_var.title("Calculator")

e = Entry(root_var, width=25, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_click(number=None):

#e.delete(0, END)
current = e.get()
e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number) )

def button_clear():
e.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
first_number = e.get()
global f_num
f_num = int(first_number)
e.delete(0, END)


def button_subtract():
second_number = e.get()
e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, f_num + int(second_number))


def button_multiply():
third_number = e.get()
e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, f_num + int(third_number))



def button_divide():
fourth_number = e.get()
e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, f_num + int(fourth_number))



def button_exponents():
fifth_number = e.get()
e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, f_num + int(fifth_number))

def button_equal():
sixth_number = e.get()
e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, f_num + int(sixth_number))

 button_1 = Button(root_var, text="1", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(1))
 button_2 = Button(root_var, text="2", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(2))
 button_3 = Button(root_var, text="3", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(3))
 button_4 = Button(root_var, text="4", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(4))
 button_5 = Button(root_var, text="5", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(5))
 button_6 = Button(root_var, text="6", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(6))
 button_7 = Button(root_var, text="7", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(7))
 button_8 = Button(root_var, text="8", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(8))
 button_9 = Button(root_var, text="9", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(9))
 button_0 = Button(root_var, text="0", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(0))

 button_addition = Button(root_var, text="+", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_add)
 button_subtraction = Button(root_var, text="-", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_subtract)
 button_multiplication = Button(root_var, text="*", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_multiply)
 button_division = Button(root_var, text="/", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_divide)
 button_exponents = Button(root_var, text="^", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_exponents)

 button_equals = Button(root_var, text="=", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_equal)

 button_clear = Button(root_var, text="C", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_clear)

  button_1.grid(row=3, column=2)
  button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
  button_3.grid(row=3, column=0)

  button_4.grid(row=2, column=2)
  button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
  button_6.grid(row=2, column=0)

  button_7.grid(row=1, column=2)
  button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
  button_9.grid(row=1, column=0)

  button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
  button_addition.grid(row=4, column=1)
  button_subtraction.grid(row=4, column=2)

  button_multiplication.grid(row=5, column=0)
  button_division.grid(row=5, column=1)
  button_exponents.grid(row=5, column=2)

  button_equals.grid(row=6, column=0)
  button_clear.grid(row=6, column=1)


  root_var.mainloop()
```

The addition operation works. I want the other operations to also be able to perform their respective tasks.

Comment: The code you've posted is not indented properly and therefore does not make sense.

Comment: You define your variable `f_num` inside the function `button_add()`. So it only get's defined once you call this function the first time. Maybe try to define `f_num`somewhere else.

Comment: You are locally refering to `f_num` in the functions. Either make it a global variable (Not recommended) or pass it as an argument

Comment: @PCM Having a global variable isn't that bad, and there is no way to pass it around as an argument. Having global variables is only a problem if you don't remember their names/what they hold.

Comment: Even though you can fix the `f_num` issue, the logic inside those functions for multiplication, division, subtraction and exponential operations are incorrect.

Comment: Ok so how do I fix the functions, @acw1668?

Comment: @PCM it is a global var:  `global f_num`

Comment: `f_num = int(first_number)`

Comment: @steTATO even though I defined it in the `button_add()` function the addition worked perfectly. All I want to know is how do I make the other 4 operators\ work without getting the f_num error.

Comment: Well thats it. If you press `button_add()` you define `f_num` but not if the first button/function you use is one of the other 4. You could either get `f_num` for each function individually, or call an extra function in the beginning that gets all the users input, no matter what button is clicked.

Comment: Could you show me a code example I didn't quite get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one of the operators is clicked, you need to save the current input number to `f_num` and the operator to another variable, for example `opr`.

Then when <kbd>=</kbd> is clicked, do the calculation based on the saved `opr`, `f_num` and current input value.

Below is an example based on your code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root_var = Tk()
root_var.title("Calculator")

e = Entry(root_var, width=25, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

f_num = opr = None

def button_click(number=None):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, current+str(number))

def button_opr(op):
    global f_num, opr
    # save the first number and operator
    try:
        f_num = int(e.get())
        opr = op
        # clear the entry
        e.delete(0, END)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

def button_clear():
    global f_num, opr
    e.delete(0, END)
    # reset first number and operator
    f_num = opr = None

def button_equal():
    global f_num, opr
    if f_num and opr:
        try:
            current = int(e.get())
            e.delete(0, END)
            if opr == "+":
                e.insert(0, f_num+current)
            elif opr == "-":
                e.insert(0, f_num-current)
            elif opr == "*":
                e.insert(0, f_num*current)
            elif opr == "/":
                e.insert(0, f_num/current)
            elif opr == "^":
                e.insert(0, f_num**current)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
    # reset first number and operator
    f_num = opr = None

button_1 = Button(root_var, text="1", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root_var, text="2", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root_var, text="3", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root_var, text="4", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root_var, text="5", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root_var, text="6", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root_var, text="7", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root_var, text="8", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root_var, text="9", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root_var, text="0", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(0))

button_addition = Button(root_var, text="+", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_opr("+"))
button_subtraction = Button(root_var, text="-", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_opr("-"))
button_multiplication = Button(root_var, text="*", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_opr("*"))
button_division = Button(root_var, text="/", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_opr("/"))
button_exponents = Button(root_var, text="^", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_opr("^"))
button_equals = Button(root_var, text="=", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_equal)
button_clear = Button(root_var, text="C", padx=50, pady=10, command=button_clear)

button_1.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="ew")
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ew")
button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew")
button_4.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="ew")
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ew")
button_6.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")
button_7.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="ew")
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
button_9.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
button_0.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="ew")

button_addition.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="ew")
button_subtraction.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="ew")
button_multiplication.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="ew")
button_division.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="ew")
button_exponents.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="ew")
button_equals.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="ew")
button_clear.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky="ew")

root_var.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, then putting all the functions into that class and declaring f_num as self.f_num.

You can also try something like this if you don't know how to use classes:

```
f_num = 0

def button_add():
    global f_num
    first_number = 10
    f_num = first_number
    


def button_subtract():
    global f_num
    second_number = 20
    print(f_num + second_number)

button_add()
button_subtract()

print(f_num)
```

Declare `f_num` outside the functions, then perform all operations on `f_num` inside the functions.
(Add `global` otherwise the value of `f_num` will not be changed)

Comment: It looks like OP is using functional programming. They might not even know what a class is. If that's the case, this answer would be useless to them.

Comment: @Yoshikaga Kira does your code help in making the remaining 4 operators work? Coz my aim is to get rid of that error and make the operators perform well.

Comment: @Yoshikaga Kira From what I understood from your answer, you want me to make f_num a class. Is that right?

Comment: No, you need to create a class, putting into __init__(self) f_num.
You can also use the code that I wrote here.

If you don't know how declare/use classes, then read this documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html